# vb.net messageboxes not displaying

Tags: vb.net, messagebox

One of my duties at my job is to enhance and maintain a mature VB.Net windows application used internally by my company.  We run 8 computers at the small company that each runs the app with no problems.

Recently we replaced one of the computers with a pretty standard notebook running Win 7 Professional with SP1 and for some reason, it won't display message boxes displayed using the normal MessageBox.Show("Message") method.

The vendor who sold us the computer says it must be the program, and I kind of sympathize with that view, but the fact is we have 8 other computers that all display their message boxes just fine.

Thought I'd post the issue here to see if anyone else has run into this and, if so, did they find a resolution?

Comment: Please edit your title before the Apostrophe Monster kills another kitten.

Comment: Do you have mcafee installed on that computer?

Comment: Changed the title, hopefully my kittens are safe...  The computer doesn't have mcafee on it, uses Panda for malware control.  As an aside, all the computers at the company use Panda, so wouldn't think it's the culprit.

Comment: Have you tried a test application that just does a `messagebox.show()` to see if it is that application, or the computer?

Comment: That is a really good question!  I work off site for most of the week, so am waiting to do that when I go in to the office on Monday.  However, even if it does turn out to work on the simple program, still won't answer why it doesn't work with the more complex program.  I agree it will be a very important and useful data point, and it could lead to searching for what the app in question does that the simple program doesn't do, but to my mind won't really answer the question of why it happens.  And, it won't tell me why it works on all the other computers and not this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to paint outside the lines a little bit and answer my own question with sort of a non-answer.

We battled that computer for about a week and a half and finally gave up and reinstalled the OS.  Problem solved.  Not really an answer because we still don't know what was going on or why reinstalling the OS fixed it.

Reinstalling was really an act of frustration/desperation as much as anything else.  In the end we were just thankful the problem went away and we could move on.  Figured I'd get this off of the unanswered questions list since I'm not really waiting for or expecting an answer at this point.